# Работа со стеком

Tags: c, c++

Есть структура, описывающая стек:

```
struct list {
  int num;
  list *previous;
};
```

И функция удаления звена из стека:

```
list *DeleteElement(list *stack) {
  list *tmp = stack;
  stack = stack->prevoius;
  delete tmp;
  return stack;
}
```

Как видно из кода, функия модифицирует переменную stack и возвращает её. Как правильно переписать код, чтобы сама функция имела тип void, а переданный параметр модифицировался, а не передавался в функцию, как копия? Как на примере с числами:

```
void mod(int &x) {
  x = x*2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void DeleteElement(list *&stack) {
  list *tmp = stack;
  stack = stack->prevoius;
  delete tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

стек обычно делают на массиве, а не на списке....

```
struct leaf {
  int num;
  list *prev;
};

struct ptr_stack {
  leaf *last;
};

void pop ( ptr_stack *stack ){
  if ( stack->last != 0 ){
    leaf *tmp = stack->last->prev;

    delete stack->last;

    stack->last = tmp;
  }
}

void push ( ptr_stack *stack, num ){
  leaf *tmp = new list;
  tmp->num = num;
  tmp->prev = stack->last;
  stack->last = tmp;
}

ptr_stack* new_stack (){
  ptr_stack *stack = new ptr_stack;
  stack->last = 0;
  return stack;
}
```